# yii zii.widgets.grid.CGridView add a button before pagination for updating

Tags: php, gridview, yii, pagination

I need to update a field and i am using check box and wanted to update the values which are checked, I have added a save button at the bottom of grid and it is working but I want to add this button before pagination link how can i do that.

### My CGridView Code:

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
        array('id' => 'web-audit-grid', 
            'dataProvider' => $model->search(), 
            'filter' => $model, 
            'columns' => array(
                'id', 
                'account_id', 
                'table', 
                'field', 
                'old_value', 
                'new_value', 
                array(
                    'header' => 'Archive', 
                    'class' => 'CDataColumn', 
                    'type' => 'raw', 
                    'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("WebAudit[delete][]",($data->archive==0)?1:0, array("value"=>$data->id,"id"=>"esid_".$data->id))')
                )
            )
        );  
?>
```

Comment: You want a footer button before pagination links in Cgridview?

Comment: yes for bulk action.

Comment: Add your cGridView code

Comment: <?php
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'web-audit-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'account_id',
        'table',
        'field',
        'old_value',
        'new_value',
        array(
            'header' => 'Archive',
            'class' => 'CDataColumn',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::checkBox("WebAudit[delete][]",($data->archive==0)?1:0, array("value"=>$data->id,"id"=>"esid_".$data->id))'
        )
    )
));
?>

Comment: Also add save button code in your question.

Comment: below that i have added this code <?php echo CHtml::imageButton((Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/Save_Btn_new.png'), array('name'=>'Search')); ?>

 <?php $this->endWidget(); ?> but it is outside grid

Comment: <?php
echo CHtml::imageButton((Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/images/Save_Btn_new.png'), array('name' => 'Search'
));
?>
<?php
$this->endWidget();
?>

Comment: Add it in your code. I cant understand it from comments

Comment: i want a button for mass action inside grid not outside grid in the footer